# Quadratic Form in Gauss-Markov Theorem

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, least-squares, gauss-markov-theorem

The following is the derivation of the Gauss-Markov Theorem in Greene's Econometric Analysis (8th ed.)

[image]
[image]

I am trying to understand two points about the passage in yellow about the quadratic form.

1. Why does $DD'$ have a quadratic form?
2. For $Var[b_o|X] \geqslant Var[b|X]]$, $DD'$ must be equal or greater than 0. Why is this true?

Comment: 1. - it's a quadratic form $v'v$, that's why it's $\ge 0$

Comment: Thanks, @Aksakal, I have edited the question

Comment: The highlighted passage *defines* what the author means by a quadratic form: it's the function $q\to q^\prime D D^\prime q.$ Since this can be rewritten as the sum of squares $(D q)^\prime (D q)$ and squares cannot be negative, it is *obvious* that its values are never negative.  (When mathematics is done rigorously, non-negative real numbers are *defined* to be those that are the squares!)

Comment: What do you mean, @whuber? Not always multiplying a matrix by its transpose yields a positive matrix. For instance, take the 2 x 2 matrix with first line [0,1] and second line [1, -1]. The result will be [1, -1];[-1, 2].

Comment: Whenever $x$ is a real-valued (column) vector, $x^\prime x$ is the sum of squares of its components. Apply this fact to the case $x=Dq.$